Не работает получение текста из сообщения telegram
у меня проблема, что я хотел сделать телеграм бота. Но по моей задумке по команде /gps бот должен принимать сообщения, в данном случае город. Но я не пойму как это сделать. Пробовал вот так:
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import telebot
import os

load_dotenv()
bot = telebot.TeleBot(os.getenv("telegram_token"))

@bot.message_handler(commands=['Start', 'start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет')

@bot.message_handler(content_types='text', commands=['gps'])
def extrtract_city_word(message):
    extracted_message = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Ты написал это:', extracted_message)

Пока для отладки я сделал так. Не пойму что тут не так.
В консоли:
(__init__.py:1222 MainThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "Threaded polling exception: A request 
to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: 
unsupported parse_mode"


Если джун, то должен справиться сам ‍♀️ тык

У тебя ошибка в bot.send_message. Текст вторым аргументом, а ты его добавляешь третьим, в котором parse_mode. Исправь на нечто такое: bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ты написал это: {message.text}')

Спасибо огромное, теперь всё нормально)
